# How to run wiremock in servlet container(tomcat)

Tags: tomcat, wiremock

I have created a maven project of wiremock to deploy it in servlet container(tomcat). My Pom.xml looks like

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.wiremock.war.poc</groupId>
    <artifactId>wiremock_poc</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.tomakehurst/wiremock -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
    <finalName>wireMockService</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and my web.xml looks a like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_9" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <listener>
        <display-name>wiremock-startup-listener</display-name>
        <listener-class>com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.servlet.WireMockWebContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>WireMockFileSourceRoot</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/wiremock</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>verboseLoggingEnabled</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>wiremock-mock-service-handler-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.servlet.WireMockHandlerDispatchingServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>RequestHandlerClass</param-name>
            <param-value>com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.StubRequestHandler</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>wiremock-mock-service-handler-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>wiremock-admin-handler-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.servlet.WireMockHandlerDispatchingServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>RequestHandlerClass</param-name>
            <param-value>com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.AdminRequestHandler</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>wiremock-admin-handler-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/__admin/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.json</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.xml</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.txt</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>json</extension>
        <mime-type>application/json</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>xml</extension>
        <mime-type>application/xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>html</extension>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>txt</extension>
        <mime-type>text/plain</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
</web-app>
```

[My project structure is given in the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hinr.png)

I build the war file using the maven war plugin as given in pom. and it build successfully. It deployed in tomcat successfully but while starting , I got following error 
**FAIL - Application at context path /wiremock could not be started**
I checked the error in **localhost.2019-04-18** i got following error

```
18-Apr-2019 15:24:25.666 SEVERE [http-apr-1011-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error configuring application listener of class com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.servlet.WireMockWebContextListener
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.servlet.WireMockWebContextListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4660)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5181)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1293)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:673)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:221)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2503)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2492)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can anyone help me on this? thanks is advance.

Comment: Can you explain what you've tried, what you expect and what you observe?

Comment: I have tried mocking with  a wiremock-standalone.jar , but now I want to deploy the wiremock server in tomcat but I am not getting how to start with it,

Comment: Have you tried the steps outlined in the documentation on [Deploying into a servlet container](http://wiremock.org/docs/getting-started/#deploying-into-a-servlet-container) and the additional suggestions by the project lead in the mailinglist: [search Tomcat](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/wiremock-user/tomcat%7Csort:date)

Comment: In the error the following caught my eye: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.servlet.WireMockWebContextListener
    at ... ` so it seems that this class is not part of the the active class path.

Answer (score 0):

You received

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.servlet.WireMockWebContextListener
```

because the WireMockWebContextListener class is not on the current classpath. You added the required library:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

but you restricted it to scope **test**. Because of that, wiremock is not added to the classpath used for running the application on Tomcat.
Just remove `<scope>test</scope>`.